# Page unload event handling in JSF

Tags: jsf, window.onunload

Is there any way to handle page unLoad event in JSF 2.0? I want to perform some data reset whenever the user move away from a particular page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported by standard JSF. Your best bet is using [OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped). Then you can just do your job in a method annotated with `@PreDestroy`.

```java
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // ...
    }
}
```